# JPS-like path finding algorithm that keeps a distance from the obstacles?

Tags: shortest-path

I am using the JPS algorithm to find the shortest path from start $S$ to goal $G$ on a binary grid where each cell can be eithe 0 (free) or 1 (obstacle). Now, I would like my algorithm to take into account the distance between the path and the obstacles and to find a path that approximates the shortest, while being "safer".

As an example, in the figure below the black path is the JPS outcome, while the red path is what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to be a bit more formal in your description to get good answers. For instance, can you just give edges/vertices close to the black borders larger weight so that they would be avoided?